# Passing parameter to api via ajax call() in POST method

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

How Ajax call works at back-hand... when I passed the data it transfers into a whole string... I need the data to be parsed as the same variable type...
Integer value implicitly converted to a string. how it happens??

```
auth:
  desig: 1
  email: "commanman@human.in"
  name: "commanMan"
  password: "********"
  staff_id: 1
```

in my console log everything seems good... but checking at backend log.. its show error

```
auth:
  desig: "1"
  email: "commanman@human.in"
  name: "commanMan"
  password: "********"
  staff_id: "1"
```

How it is implicitly converted??

This is my ajax call

```
jQuery.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: 'POST',
          data: data,
          dataType: "json",
          // contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          success: function(result) {
            console.log(result)
          },
       });
```

> How to avoid this implicit conversion while passing a value to API via ajax call?

Comment: The implicit type conversion is platform dependent. So your server will determine how this occurs. A Java platform will perform differently than a .NET and differently than NodeJS, etc. What is your server platform?

Comment: You should also realize that the underlying transport protocol is HTTP - the first "T" stands for TEXT. Regardless of how much you want those numbers to be integer types, HTTP transfers them as text. So it is possible there is no conversion at all.

Comment: Yup! Thanks @RandyCasburn for replying... Yeah i agree with your point HTTP transfers data as text. After I added explicit conversion at backend, it works.. Once again thanks man!